# REGEXP_LIKE Oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of 100 words that I need to do a  pattern match on 55 Million rows of data. Is there a way to create a list of words and pass the list through the REGEXP_LIKE function, instead of using the `| (or)` statement multiple times, can a list be input instead?

```
Search *
From table
Where REGEXP_LIKE(C1, 'wordlword2letc...', 'i');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a list of words as **`pattern`** in **`REGEXP_LIKE`**.

**`pattern`** is the regular expression and usually is text literal and cannot be more than 512 bytes.

What you can possibly do is, store the *words you're trying to search* in separate table/column and then use **`LIKE`** condition in your query as you're just trying to search for the occurrence of the words and not expecting regular expression search support.

So, if there is a table/column (new_table.col) which stores your input items to search for, your query might look like (using `UPPER` function to ensure case insensitive search as you were trying) -

```
SELECT a.* FROM table a, new_table b WHERE UPPER(a.col1) LIKE UPPER(b.col);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply